# MySQL dynamic variable getting truncated

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am writing a stored procedure in which I am using dynamic variables to define a block of SQL. I then create a prepared statement from the dynamic variable and execute it.

When my SQL gets longer than 255 chars it gets truncated (presumably a limit dynamic variables).

```
set @NEW_CAMPAIGN_SQL = concat(
    'CREATE TABLE `', CAMPAIGN_TABLE, '` (',
      '`id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,',
      '`code` char(', _CODE_LEN, ') NOT NULL default \'\',',
      '`status` tinyint(1) unsigned NOT NULL default 1,',
      'PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),',
      'KEY `code_idx` (`code`),',
      'KEY `status_idx` (`status`)',
    ') ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1'
);

PREPARE NEW_CAMPAIGN_STMT FROM @NEW_CAMPAIGN_SQL; 
EXECUTE NEW_CAMPAIGN_STMT; 
Deallocate prepare NEW_CAMPAIGN_STMT;
```

I tried just declaring NEW_CAMPAIGN_SQL as a non-dynamic variable but then the prepared statement fails.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the error. Can you copy-paste the Mysql error you are getting?

Comment: Yep, it was my own fault (see my answer below). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah crap. As is typically the case it was my own stupidity and not the fault of MySQL in any way. I was returning the SQL string to an OUT param that was varchar(255).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Check MySQL's [Set Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set-option.html). You don't need the `@` inside the stored procedure (are you coming from SQL Server?). You should also check [Declare for Local Variables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-local-variable.html) as this might help you.

Comment: Pretty sure the @ is needed for using prepared statements inside a stored procedure.